# Estimation of the total variation with a slice

Tags: sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Let $Q=(0,1)\times (0,1)$ and $u\in BV(Q)$ where $BV$ stands for bounded variation.

My question, is there exist a slice $S:=\{t\}\times (0,1)\subset Q$ such that 
$$
\|u\|_{BV(S)}\leq \|u\|_{BV(Q)}?
$$

I know a similar result holds in sobolev space, so I am wondering is there a similar one hold in $BV$ space.